# Renaming columns using the first part of the string in the first row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, split, reformatting

I imported a dataset with different column names that all start with Area, Mean, StdDev but have () with different strings inside.
What I want to do is split the string in each column by the "( )" and set the first part as the column headers and the second part as a row under that header. I was looking into stacking and unstacking similar to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67205063/rename-columns-using-part-of-the-string-in-pandas) or .split() and .explode() in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71175458/splitting-row-into-multiple-rows-in-pandas-dataframe) but I don't know how to apply it to mine. It is slightly different.
My initial dataframe looks like df1. What I am trying to do is df2 but at the end, I am trying to get a format like df3. If you can help me getting to either df2 or df3 that would be great, otherwise I can keep playing around with it after I mange to get it to look like df2.

My dataset looks like:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
1: {'1': "Area(E10_1_nucleus)", '2': 435}, 
2: {'1': "Mean(E10_1_nucleus)", '2': 313},
3: {'1': "StdDev(E10_1_nucleus)", '2': 150}, 
4: {'1': "Area(E10_1_cytoplasm)", '2': 635},
5: {'1': "Mean(E10_1_cytoplasm)", '2': 847}, 
6: {'1': "StdDev(E10_1_cytoplasm)", '2': 321}})
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
df2= pd.DataFrame({
1: {'1': "Area", '2':'E10_1_nucleus','3': 435}, 
2: {'1': "Mean",'2':'E10_1_nucleus' ,'3': 313},
3: {'1': "StdDev",'2':'E10_1_nucleus' ,'3': 150}, 
4: {'1': "Area",'2':'E10_1_cytoplasm' ,'3': 635},
5: {'1': "Mean",'2':'E10_1_cytoplasm' ,'3': 847}, 
6: {'1': "StdDev",'2':'E10_1_cytoplasm' ,'3': 331}})
```

The final desired format is the following:

```
df3= pd.DataFrame({
'Label': {'1':'E10_1_nucleus' ,'2':'E10_1_cytoplasm' },
'Area': {'1': 435,'2':635}, 
'Mean': {'1': 313,'2':847},
'StdDev': {'1': 150,'2':331}})
```

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: I tried out = df1.stack().str.split(r'\(',expand=True).set_index(0,append=True)[1].reset_index(level=1,drop=True).unstack() but I lose the numbers that correspond to each and I also get the following error: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: I could use: out = df1.stack().str.split(r'\(',expand=True) but I need to find a way to keep the numbers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```
df = df.transpose()
df = (
    df
    .assign(
        Aggregate=df["1"].str.replace(r"\(.*\)", "", regex=True),
        Label=df.pop("1").str.extract(r"\((.*?)\)", expand=True)
    )
    .pivot(index="Label", columns="Aggregate", values="2")
    .astype(int)
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)

print(df)

             Label Area Mean StdDev
0  E10_1_cytoplasm  635  847    321
1    E10_1_nucleus  435  313    150
```

Comment: Wow, this worked! I did have a question though, what does the last line do? The df1.columns.name=None. Also, I get the desired final format, is there a way to keep the numbers as int64 and not objects? My actual dataframe will have a lot more columns and it will vary, so manually changing them to int64 would not be the best option.

Comment: The last line removes the index header after pivoting. See edit for .astype(int) before resetting index

Comment: Hello Jason, what if I have more columns other than just '"2"? Would values just be values=[  ]? So it would just get the remainder columns?

Comment: If I understand your question: index=["Label", "3"]

Comment: So I would have multiple columns. "2",3", etc. This will vary for each data frame I import so it won't be consistent each time. Is there a way to do values=[:,:]?